# cordova websocket onready for android

Tags: javascript, cordova, websocket

Best regards,
I have tried several websocket plugins, but none worked for me. 
I can't know what's wrong because when I try the code in a browser, it works successfully but after building the apk, nothing happens.
I have checked the configuration of config.xml, permissions and plugins.
me guess that Jelly beans inbrowser doesn't support websocket (we already know that) but even within the plugins? just a guess.
I am using jwebsocket as a websocket server. 
cordova version 3.5.0 
please tell me what is the wrong in my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    function onDeviceReady() {
       var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.6:8787/');
ws.onmessage = function () {
  alert('a message was recieved');
};
ws.onopen = function () {
ws.send('I just connected!');
};
    }
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="websocket.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the `websocket.js` located? Is it on the phone or the webserver?. Also you will need to enable CORS. You can search stackoverflow to find how to enable CORS.

Comment: Hello Frank, Websocket.js in www in my cordova project (on the phone), CORS is enabled from the apache httpd.conf.

Comment: What is websocket.js ? Is it a library for websockets? Do you require only a single file `websocket.js` for using websockets. If it is a library then it will require additonal files for completing its task. By placing the websocket.js file in `www` directory it will start searching for other files in the same directory, which as per your comments will not be available. Hence it will fail. You need to enable CORS at the client as well there is a parameter `origin` in config.xml that needs 2 b set. Also while creating the `WebSocket` object by the `new` operator check what is the return value.

Comment: Hello, websocket.js is a configuration file for websocket.i.e. timeout, handshake, etc .. AND not additional files required (I see your point here). I did enabled CORS in the android project from config.xml, I am using a plugin from github (https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket). I read in the issues section some people having my same problem and no fix is found. I'll give it a try tomorrow :)

Comment: why don't you try `socket.io`? It seems fit for your purpose.